# Spring Boot + Gradle - where to put environment configuration?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot, build.gradle

I was working on a simple application in Spring Boot. It was developed locally (and it works) with:

- Gradle,
- H2 database with connection properties set in `application.properties` placed on project's root
- Maven folders structure (`src/main/groovy`, `src/main/resources`, etc.)

Now it's the time when I'd like to deploy it to the Openshift, so I need to create an additional, production configuration with a MySQL settings, but I don't know where to put it and how to use it.

So my questions are:

1. What should I do to have two different configurations (`development` and `production`)?
2. Where to put the configuration files?
3. Do I have to change something in the `build.gradle`?
4. How to **build** the app with a development or production config?
5. How to **run** the app with a development or production config?
6. What are the best practices for creating multiple environment configurations?

I'm rather a frontend dev and all these backend stuff are not obvious for me, so please consider it in your answers.

This is the content of my current `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'groovy'
}

jar {
    baseName = 'myproject'
    version =  '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0')
    compile localGroovy()
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What should I do to have two different configurations (development and production)?

In your case, you can use a profiles to achieve it. You can read about it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). For each profile you can have [specific application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) file (named `application-%PROFILE_NAME%.properties`, like `application-prod.properties`, the same is true for `.yml` configuration files) And you have to specify what profile yo use then you are starting your app via command line switch for example like so:

```
--spring.profiles.active=prod
```

> Where to put the configuration files?

Just in the same place as your `application.properties` file.

> Do I have to change something in the build.gradle?

No, you don't need to modify your build script. Since all specific configurations are needed for running your application, not for building.

> How to build the app with a development or production config?

You don't need to build it with some specific configuration, just run it with it.

> How to run the app with a development or production config?

As it was said earlier - just  specify what profile to use when starting the application.

> What are the best practices for creating multiple environment configurations?

As for me, if you use a spring - to use profiles and profile specific configuration and bean-definitions.

Comment: You helped me a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate `application-dev.properties` along side your existing application.properties files as outlined here to contain your h2 config https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties and then activate this when running in dev by passing in the following argument when starting the app `--spring.profiles.active=dev` you could do the same for production i.e. `application-prod.properties` and keep the common configuration in `application.properties`.

Comment: Where to put these config files?On project's root? Will they be included in the generated war?

Comment: Put them in `src/main/resources` then they will be included in the generated war / jar. If this is not what you want you can load a file from outside the artifact by setting spring.config.location.