# How to package jar depends on profile on gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I’m using gradle & jenkins & spring boot.

I want to package my project depends on profile by passing argument like maven.

ex) `mvn package -Pprofile=op`

I configure my yml file by changing value of `spring.profile.active` now.

But I want to change my yml spring.profile.active value by passing parameter.
ex) `gradle build -Pprofile op`

Is is possible? How to set my gradle script?

Comment: Active profiles are evaluated at runtime, not build time. Is there a reason you need to set it at build time here?

Comment: For convenience. I want to deploy my jar file to several remote server depends on profile like maven that I mentioned above. Is there any suggestion??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44277309/175554 helps ?